# SQL - Rank or Order by "human" Relevance

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, innodb

Looking implement a ranking/order by feature that ranks products by the way we as humans regard as relevant, not what a computer regards as relevant. Currently I have this sql statment

```
select MATCH(productName) AGAINST('xyz' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevant...
... ORDER BY relevant DESC
```

These seems to work well, with regards to how many times a 'keyword' appears within the recordset, but its very Yay or Nay, if you know what I mean.

However, searching for "computer console" (in the unlikely event), I would like to see "Playstation", "xBox", "Nintendo" Although I never actually typed these keywords into the search field.

Search for "ladder" I personally would expect to see ladders for height access not the board game "snakes and ladders" or clothing with a ladder patten.

Some with "Iron" I wound not expect "Iron man bedding" to appear within the first page.

Is there an industry way of achieving such thing or does anyone have any ideas how this could be accomplished. i.e secondry table with keywords / search terms matching product_id.

Regards

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: This is a _nontrivial_ task.  It Google more than a decade to become more than a simplistic search engine.  Meanwhile, the competitors gave up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, one is to assume this is not that easy to do. So maybe a work around would be setting additional keywords with variations of terminology relating to each product.

Comment: This is really too broad question for SO. Additionally you may want to use some technology that is less than 20 years old - [asp-classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) is not something you can easily find any help with nowdays... I doubt you can even get mysql access from it. Look for [asp.net-mvc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) if you want to use Microsfot's framework.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly the same situation as yours but it may help you.

I designed a relevancy-based search results system for a large content management system I developed at my work.

Content comprises a title, the content and a hidden keywords field (words that should be used for search but are not included in the title or content). [there's lots more fields, but these three will do for demonstration of concept]

When content is added it gets indexed: some non alpha-numeric characters are removed, each word is stemmed (ie. educate, education, educator, educates, etc all get indexed as the same word), some words are converted to another based on some internal rules, and then they all get stored in an index.

When a search is done the system does the same as above to each keyword (removes unwanted characters, stemming, conversion based on internal rules).

The system then gets a list of content that has each of the parsed search keywords anywhere in any of those fields.

My code then parses each of the matching results: First it looks for all of they keywords existing consecutively in one of the fields; and if it doesn't find the search phrase it then iteratively [made up word] looks for smaller groups of keywords until found (ie. if 4 search keywords are entered it tries all 4 first, then 3, then 2, then 1 if they aren't all found together)

Based on how many of the keywords were found consecutively the system applies a score to the search result. Higher scores are given based on whether the keyword(s) were found in the title, content or keywords field [this took some fine tuning] and also how close it/they were found close to the start of the field.

The results are then given to the client based on this score.

The system works very well in our situation, particularly the grouped keywords part makes for good results.

You could use a similar system in your situation. A search for "ladder" would order a product like "Ladder - extra large" before "Snakes and Ladders Game".

For "computer console" you could add terms like these to a hidden keywords field.

Note that parsing the list for relevancy takes a bit of server resources so this type of system would only be suitable where you have sufficient infrastructure available or where the list of content is not large.